# cannot unsubscribe ActionsSubject from ngrx/store

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I use `ngrx/store` to implement login actions which gets date from subscribe to a store. The login component is a modal, when I type a wrong password, I get `data.type === 'LOGIN_FAILED'`, however, when I close the modal and re-open it, the data action is still `LOGIN_FAILED` instead of `INIT`. Therefore, the login actions are not unsubscribe, I tried to manually unsubscribe the subscription, but it does not work. How can I unsubscribe the login actions properly?

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChildren, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

// shared
import { ToasterService } from '../../shared/providers/toaster-service/toaster.service';

// ngx-bootstrap
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service';

// ngrx
import { ActionsSubject } from '@ngrx/store';

// rxjs
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

  loading = <boolean>false;
  actionSub = new Subscription();
  errorMessage = <string>'';

constructor(
    private actionsSubj: ActionsSubject,
    private toastService: ToasterService,
    private bsModalRef: BsModalRef,
  ) {
    this.actionSub = this.actionsSubj.subscribe((data: any) => {
      // listen to action of setting tokens successfully / failed
      console.log(data);
      if (data.type === 'LOGIN_FAILED') {
        if (data.payload.error.error.data.type === 'WrongCredentialsException') {
          // hide spinner for login button
          this.loading = false;
          this.errorMessage = 'Wrong Credentials';
        else {
          this.loading = false;
          this.toastService.showError('An error happened when trying to login. Please try again later.');
        }
      } else if (data.type === 'SET_TOKEN') {
        this.bsModalRef.hide();
      }
    });
  } 

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.actionSub.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Comment: Do you create a new component for every login try ?

Comment: @ibenjelloun nope, if login fails, the modal remains, only successful login will close the modal automatically.

Comment: Does it mean that the `ngOnDestroy` is executed only when you succesfully login ? You can add a break point in the `ngOnDestroy` function to debug.

Comment: @ibenjelloun nope, `ngOnDestroy` executes when the component is closed

Comment: You have your answer. It does not unsubscribe because of what you said.

Comment: @ibenjelloun imagine you have a pop-up login modal, and 2 buttons for close and login. The login modal can be closed by: successful login (automatically), or press close button. Both cases can execute `ngOnDestroy`, but the subscription is not unsubscribe if I press close button, even though it should be. I assume that you are not really clear with my issue, so I just break it down here. Thanks for you concern anw.

Comment: Please add some code of the popup declaration and what happens when you click close. The component is probably not destroyed.

Answer (score 5):

This is because `ActionsSubject` is a `BehaviorSubject` under the hood, meaning it will store the latest action.

For your case you should be using `ScannedActionsSubject` which is a `Subject` under the hood.

I would also encourage to handle your forms with `@ngrx/effects` - https://blog.angularindepth.com/start-using-ngrx-effects-for-this-e0b2bd9da165

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this.