# ngrx ActionsSubject doesn't complete in a modale

Tags: angular, ngrx

In a mat dialog I'm using ActionsSubject
to listen for a dispatch action and set the flag
closed to true.

// Facade

```
sellProduct(data: ProductSellRequestDto): void {
  this.store.dispatch(MarketActions.sellProductMarketAccount({ data }));
}
OnSellProductMarketAccountSuccess(): Observable<{
  data: MarketAccountCompleteDto;
}> {
  return this.actionsSubject.pipe(
    ofType(MarketActions.sellProductMarketAccountSuccess)
  );
}
```

// Dialog

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.sold = false;
  this.subscription.add(
    this.marketAccountFacade
      .OnSellProductMarketAccountSuccess()
      .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log('checkout dual');
        this.sold = true;
      })
  );
}
confirm() {
  const data: ProductSellRequestDto = {
    userId: this.data.userId,
    productCode: this.data.product.code,
    productQuantity: this.data.quantity
  };
  this.marketAccountFacade.sellProduct(data);
}
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

It works fine the first time I open the dialog
but if I re open it the code enter in the subscribe
and set the closed flag to true.

The question is why on earth the code enter in the subscribe
block when there is no action of type  MarketActions.sellProductMarketAccountSuccess when I re open the modal?

### WORK IT OUT

Using https://ngrx.io/api/store/ScannedActionsSubject thanks to
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52640621

```
OnSellProductMarketCaveauSuccess(): Observable<{
    data: MarketAccountCompleteDto;
  }> {
    return this.scannedActionsSubject.pipe(
      ofType(MarketActions.sellProductMarketAccountSuccess)
    );
  }
```

Comment: where is the method `confirm()` called?

Comment: It's called from the template of the modal like <button (click)="confirm()"

Answer (score 1):

try using an unsubAll prop, pipe, and takeUntil instead of adding to a list of subscriptions

```
private this.unsubAll: Subject<any>;

constructor(){
    this.unsubAll = new Subject();
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.sold = false;    
    this.marketAccountFacade
       .OnSellProductMarketAccountSuccess()
       .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubAll))
       .subscribe((data) => {
           console.log('checkout dual');
           this.sold = true;
       })
}

ngOnDestroy(){
    this.unsubAll.next();
    this.unsubAll.complete();
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/store/src/actions_subject.ts it should do it under the hood :(